# Monocular SLAM depth reconstruction

Tags: slam, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to derive the inverse depth equation used in monocular SLAM algorithms. Specifically the equation 8 of the ORB SLAM [paper](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~raulmur/MurTardosRSS15.pdf)

I am very close, except I do not understand where the (u_j-c) term comes form. I get the same formulae with only the c (principal point) component.

I am thinking it is because u_j in this case is indexed from the start of the epipolar line instead of the image (0,0). Is this correct?

Best,
Marc

Comment: for the interested I have made a similar post on redit with some discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/computervision/comments/7lh53o/monocular_slam_depth_reconstruction/?st=jbnnja6p&sh=46d2de7b